# Guarantee that no error is thrown in Swift 3 do-catch?

Tags: ios, swift

If I have an asynchronous function that throws an error, how can I make sure no error is thrown before some more functions are executed?

```
do {
    try foo()
} catch {
    print("error: \(error)")
}
// HOW TO KNOW IF THE CALL WAS SUCCESSFUL HERE
```

I can have a variable that I change if an error is thrown, but it may be changed in some time if the call is asynchronous. I need to find a way to pause until `foo()` stops executing so I can be sure no error is thrown.

Comment: https://appventure.me/2015/06/19/swift-try-catch-asynchronous-closures/

Comment: Usual way: Put all *good* code in the `do` scope after `try`.

Comment: @vadian I'd probably prefer leaving the scope within the `catch` block, guaranteeing that `foo()` was a success if the code below the `do`-`catch` block was reached.